# How started with google docs in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a task to implement into web asp.net project (web site) a google docs solutions for manage with documents like word/excel. Now I read about Google Documents List Data API v2.0 on http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs.
 I'm getting the file from google docs like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) 
            {                              
                DocumentsService myService = new DocumentsService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
                myService.setUserCredentials("your_email_here@gmail.com", "test");

                DocumentsListQuery query = new DocumentsListQuery();
                DocumentsFeed feed = myService.Query(query);

                Console.WriteLine("Your docs: ");
                foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
                {
                    Label1.Text = entry.Title.Text;
                }                                                   
            }
```

I understand google docs like some word application that works in browser. How I can view file in browser like this???

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Each entry in feed.Entries contains a URL to the document. Use that.